# FirstViewController over another SecondViewController where SecondViewController is clickable

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to create universal alert that appears on the top most view controller while the bottom viewcontroller is still clickable. 
This alert is just a 20 points height status line that inform user about network reachability. How can I make UIViewController not user interactable?

Comment: _while the bottom viewcontroller is still clickable_ ? _How can I make UIViewController not user interactable_ . So , you want it to interact with the user or not?

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi I need top vc NOT interactable
And under vc IS interactable!

Comment: @Said-AbdullaAtkaev only the top VC is visible on the screen, bottom VC will not be visible on the screen, how would interact with it?

Comment: add the alert(UIView) to the window property to achieve the same

Comment: @EhsanSaddique the top vc is 99% transparent

Comment: So, that, _Top vc_ , that you're saying, is that a `UIViewController` or `UIView` or `UIAlertController` because if that is a complete screen `UIViewController`, then you cannot interact with the one that is under it, since it must be blocked by the `ViewController` at the top

Comment: @iOSer create second UIWindow with 
`let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: window.frame)
alertWindow.windowLevel = .alert` ?

Comment: @Said-AbdullaAtkaev you don't have to create a new instance of UIWindow. Rather use the existing UIWindow. like so `guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else {
            print("Some thing wrong with Window initialization!!")
            return
        }`
and then add the subview as you'd normally do and then animate it to show for 20 seconds based on network change

Comment: @iOSer can you please write some code for example?

Comment: @Said-AbdullaAtkaev Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Please note that I do not use Storyboard or XIB***
*Also if you are targeting iOS11 and above you would need to use safeAreaLayoutGuide while using autolayout code*

The solution is two folds.

First, create a Base View Controller and have all your view controllers that need to show the alert to extend from that Base View Controller.

Then create a new swift file, a subclass of NSObject. Lets say NetworkAlerter.swift and copy paste the code below (as appropriate)

```
import UIKit

class NetworkAlerter: NSObject {

var window :UIWindow? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow

var alertShowingConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint?
var alertHidingConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint?

var closeTimer : Timer? = nil

public lazy var networkIndicatorLabel : UILabel = {
    let label : UILabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    return label
}()


override init() {
    super.init()
    createSubviews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

deinit {
    print("Time to deinit")
    networkIndicatorLabel.removeFromSuperview()
}

func createSubviews() {
    guard let window = window else {
        print("Some thing wrong with Window initialization!!")
        return
    }
    window.addSubview(networkIndicatorLabel)
    addAutolayout()
}

func addAutolayout() {
    guard let window = window else {
        print("Some thing wrong with Window initialization!!")
        return
    }
    alertShowingConstraint = networkIndicatorLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.topAnchor)
    alertHidingConstraint = networkIndicatorLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.topAnchor)
    alertHidingConstraint?.isActive = true
    networkIndicatorLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    networkIndicatorLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    networkIndicatorLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
}

func showNetworkAlerter(networkAvailable: Bool) {
    guard let window = window else {
        print("Some thing wrong with Window initialization!!")
        return
    }
    invalidateAndKillTimer()
    closeTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(dismissNetworkAlerter), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    if networkAvailable {
        networkIndicatorLabel.text = "Available"
        networkIndicatorLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    } else {
        networkIndicatorLabel.text = "Not Available"
        networkIndicatorLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    window.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        if (self.alertHidingConstraint?.isActive)! {
            self.alertHidingConstraint?.isActive = false
        }
        if !(self.alertShowingConstraint?.isActive)! {
            self.alertShowingConstraint?.isActive = true
        }
        window.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: { _ in
    })
}

@objc func dismissNetworkAlerter() {
    invalidateAndKillTimer()
    guard let window = window else {
        print("Some thing wrong with Window initialization!!")
        return
    }
    window.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        if (self.alertShowingConstraint?.isActive)! {
            self.alertShowingConstraint?.isActive = false
        }
        if !(self.alertHidingConstraint?.isActive)! {
            self.alertHidingConstraint?.isActive = true
        }
        window.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (done) in
    }
}

// MARK:- Timer Related
private func invalidateAndKillTimer() -> Void {
    if (closeTimer != nil) {
        closeTimer?.invalidate()
        closeTimer = nil
    }
}
```

}

Then move back Base View Controller. Right on top copy paste the following

```
var networkAlertLauncher : NetworkAlerter? = nil
```

and then find an appropriate place in Base View Controller and paste the following:

```
func showAlertBar(networkAvailabilityStatus: Bool) -> Void {
        if networkAlertLauncher != nil {
            networkAlertLauncher = nil
        }

        networkAlertLauncher = NetworkAlerter()
        networkAlertLauncher?.showNetworkAlerter(networkAvailable: networkAvailabilityStatus)
    }
```

Now the function showAlertBar will be accessible from all the view controllers that you have extended from Base View Controller. You can invoke it like so:
`self.showAlertBar(networkAvailabilityStatus: false)` or `self.showAlertBar(networkAvailabilityStatus: true)`

Comment: Lemme know if you have any issue implementing the same